# Как сменить сцену в Godot при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: godot

Я добавил кнопки в свою 2D игру и не знаю как их заставить работать . Я пробовал искать в Google но ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Сигнал из `button` в `control`, там должна появиться функция. В функции прописать:

```
get_tree().change_scene('res/sceneName')
```

Answer (score 0):

В Godot 4

```
get_tree().change_scene_to_file('Имя_файла.tscn') //Самый простой способ
```